# AJAX in Microsoft Office Web App

Tags: javascript, ms-office

I was coding an app for Office, where i planned to use AJAX to load contents dynamically from a external website to the office app. I have the following JS  function. When the execution reaches to `a.open()` function, it shows an error:

```
 Unhandled exception at line 31, column 21 in https://localhost:44304/App/Home/Home.js

 0x80070005 - JavaScript runtime error: Access is denied.
```

-

```
function getDataFromSelection() {
    Office.context.document.getSelectedDataAsync(Office.CoercionType.Text,
        function (result) {
            if (result.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {

                var a = new XMLHttpRequest();
                a.onreadystatechange = function () {
                    if (a.readyState == 4 && a.status == 200) {
                        var jSONstr = a.responseText;
                        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(jSONstr);
                        showSearch(obj);
                    }
                };

                a.open("GET", "http://some.external.site/page.php?query=" + result.value, true); //This has got the error
                a.send();
            }
            else {
                app.showNotification('Damn!:', result.error.message);
            }
        }
    );
}
```

Is AJAX not supported in Office Apps? How can i do the exact thing the other (working) way?

PS: I am using Visual Studio 2012 On Win8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is triggered because you tried to make a cross site request via ajax.

A browser rarely allows this kind of requests, so you should find a workaround making a JSONP request or an ajax request to a server-side script that handles the server-to-server communication.